# Determine whether the series converges or diverges. (Limit Comparison Test)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How would I go about finding what to compare this to?
I tried comparing it to $\frac{1}{n^4}$, but I ended up getting $\infty$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  = \frac{(5+2n)}{(1+n^2)^2}$$

Comment: you have $n$ in the numerator, and $n^4$ in the denominator.  Compare it to $\frac 2{n^3}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use $u_n=\sum\dfrac{1}{n^3}$

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$a_n = \frac{(5+2n)}{(1+n^2)^2}$$ for any $n$, $$1+n^2>n^2\implies\frac{(5+2n)}{(1+n^2)^2}<\frac{(5+2n)}{n^4}\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<5\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$$ and both summations are convergent (p-series).

So,$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \frac{(5+2n)}{(1+n^2)^2}<\frac{5\pi ^4}{90}+2\zeta (3)=\frac{\pi ^4}{18}+2\zeta (3)\approx 7.81573$$